# How to convert the sql query into magento query in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I want to take the increment id from sales order table and status should be complete.I have created one custom table called `hydrogen_xml_generation`.

Initially the xml generated status is `0`. Once the xml is generated it will be `1`. How to write the below query in Magento 2.

```
$sales_shipment = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT increment_id FROM sales_order WHERE status = 'complete' AND sales_order.increment_id NOT IN (SELECT increment_id FROM hydrogen_xml_generation WHERE xml_generated = '1')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

First, inject the `OrderRepository` and the `yourCustomModuleRepository` to the constructor parameters:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Namespace\Module\Model\ModuleFactory $moduleFactory
) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->moduleFactory = $moduleFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$xml_generated = $this->moduleFactory->create();
$columnValues = $xml_generated->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('xml_generated',1)->getColumnValues('increment_id')
$orderResult = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$orders = $orderResult->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',array('nin' => $columnValues);
```

Comment: Hi Piyush thanks for the help i need for one more query.please help i am a fresher.

Comment: yes let me know , what issue you are facing

Comment: $details = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT sales_order.customer_id , sales_invoice.increment_id , sales_invoice.grand_total , sales_invoice.created_at , sales_order_payment.method  FROM sales_order inner join sales_invoice on sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order.entity_id inner join sales_order_payment on sales_order_payment.parent_id = sales_order.entity_id WHERE sales_order.increment_id = '" .$increment_id. "'");

Comment: $update_xml_generated = ("INSERT INTO hydrogen_xml_generation (increment_id,xml_generated) VALUES('" .$increment_id. "' , '1')");

Comment: $connection->query($update_xml_generated);

Comment: These three queries i need to convert could you please help me.First time i am doing this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask another  question for this

Comment: yes i have asked in another question.simply i put here

Comment: Okay will check there as well,  If this answer has helped, you can mark it as accepted

Comment: ok I will put all the 3 quiries and check .thanks